# Need help based on conditions in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a question about SQL Server.

Table `patient`:

```
pn |  code  |  date      |   doctorcode
---------------------------------------
1  |  10    |2015-02-19  |   100
1  |  10    |2015-02-19  |   101
1  |  10    |2015-02-19  |   102
2  |  10    |2015-02-12  |   101
2  |  10    |2015-02-13  |   102
2  |  10    |2015-02-14  |   103
3  |  10    |2015-02-15  |   103
3  |  10    |2015-02-18  |   104  
3  |  10    |2015-02-26  |   105
```

Table `Patientref`:

```
pn |  code  |  sdate      |   edate      | Status
-------------------------------------------------
1  |  10    |2015-02-13   |   2015-02-19 |  1
1  |  10    |2015-02-19   |   2015-03-24 |  2
1  |  10    |2015-04-28   |   2015-05-08 |  4
2  |  10    |2015-02-08   |   2015-02-19 |  4
2  |  10    |2015-02-09   |   2015-02-19 |  2
2  |  10    |2015-02-10   |   2015-02-19 |  2
2  |  10    |2015-02-11   |   2015-02-18 |  1
3  |  10    |2015-02-10   |   2015-02-17 |  4
3  |  10    |2015-02-10   |   2015-02-17 |  3
3  |  10    |2015-02-11   |   2015-02-18 |  3
2  |  10    |2015-04-10   |   2015-05-19 |  2
3  |  10    |2015-02-11   |   2015-02-18 |  1
3  |  10    |2015-02-26   |   2015-03-18 |  1
```

Here we need consider patient dates that fall between `sdate` and `edate` of the `patientrefs` table, and then we need to consider the highest `status` values in order (for example, the highest values in order - 2 is first highest, 4 is second highest, 3 is third highest, and 1 is fourth highest value)

If the date falls between multiple different `sdate` and `edate` with the same status values, then we need to consider the latest `sdate` value and from that entire record we need to extract that value.

Examples: patient

```
pn |  code  |  date      |   doctorcode
2  |  10    |2015-02-12  |   101
2  |  10    |2015-02-13  |   102
2  |  10    |2015-02-14  |   103
```

Table : Patientref:

```
pn |  code  |  sdate      |   edate      | Status
2  |  10    |2015-02-08   |   2015-02-19 |  4
2  |  10    |2015-02-09   |   2015-02-19 |  2
2  |  10    |2015-02-10   |   2015-02-19 |  2
2  |  10    |2015-02-11   |   2015-02-18 |  1
```

Here, `pn=2` values have dates which fall between `sdate` and `edate` of patientref table.  Then we give highest values status is 2, and status 2 values have two records, then we go for max sdate(latest sdate). Then this `pn=2` latest sdates is `2015-02-10` and we need to retrieve the corresponding `edate` and `status` values.

Based on this, the desired output is below:

```
pn |  code  |  date      |   doctorcode | sdate     |edate      |status
1  |  10    |2015-02-19  |   100        |2015-02-19 |2015-03-24 | 2
1  |  10    |2015-02-19  |   101        |2015-02-19 |2015-03-24 | 2
1  |  10    |2015-02-19  |   102        |2015-02-19 |2015-03-24 | 2
2  |  10    |2015-02-12  |   101        |2015-02-10 |2015-02-19 | 2
2  |  10    |2015-02-13  |   102        |2015-02-10 |2015-02-19 | 2
2  |  10    |2015-02-14  |   103        |2015-02-10 |2015-02-19 | 2
3  |  10    |2015-02-15  |   103        |2015-02-10 |2015-02-17 | 4
3  |  10    |2015-02-18  |   104        |2015-02-11 |2015-02-18 | 3
3  |  10    |2015-02-26  |   105        |2015-02-26 |2015-03-18 | 1
```

I tried it like this:

```
select  
    a.pn, a.code, a.doctorcode, a.date,
    b.sdate, b.edate, b.status
from   
    patient a
left join 
    (select 
         b.pn, b.code, b.sdate, b.edate,
         row_number() over (partition by pn, org
                            order by case when status=2 then 1 when status=4 then 2  when status=3 then 3 when status=1 then 4 end desc,sdate desc) as rn
    from patientref) b on a.pn = b.pn and a.code = b.code 
                       and a.rn = 1
                       and a.date between  b.sdate and b.edate
```

But it does not give the expected result. How can I write the query to achieve this task in SQL Server?

Comment: Why don't you try breaking down the problem into smaller queries and put them into temp tables

Comment: HI can you please give some ideas to split this logic into temp table

Answer (score 1):

First off, to handle the status sorting you should really have a table in your system showing how they can be sorted. This would just be a table that has the status ID and a sort order column showing sorting priority. However, for your query you can just create a table variable to manage it.

```
declare @statuses table
([status] int,
sort_order int)

insert into @statuses ([status], sort_order) values (2,0);
insert into @statuses ([status], sort_order) values (4,1);
insert into @statuses ([status], sort_order) values (3,2);
insert into @statuses ([status], sort_order) values (1,3);
```

Then you can use CROSS APPLY to query your patient table and use the highest priority record from your patientref table:

```
select
p.pn,
p.code,
p.date,
p.doctorcode,
ca.sdate,
ca.edate,
ca.status
from patient p
cross apply 
    (select
    top 1 
    pr.pn,
    pr.code,
    pr.sdate,
    pr.edate,
    pr.status
    from patientref pr 
    inner join @statuses s on pr.status = s.status
    where pr.pn = p.pn
    and pr.code = p.code
    and p.date between pr.sdate and pr.edate
    order by s.sort_order, pr.sdate desc) as ca
```

Comment: HI given query will come expected result. I tried like below  select p.pn,p.code.p.date,p.doctorcode,ca.sdate,ca.edate,ca.status from patient p croos apply (select top1 pr.pn,pr.code,pr.sdate,pr.edate,pr.status from patientref pr where pr.pn=p.pn and pr.code=p.code and p.date between pr.sdate and pr.edate order by case when pr.status=2 then 1 when pr.status=4 then 2  when pr.status=3 then 3 when pr.status=1 then 4 end desc,pr.sdate )pr.its working fine. is it possible to do same result with left join query.if possible please tell me that query.